# CSS @media print body on viewport width higher than 100 shrinks content, but not on Safari

Tags: html, css

In Chrome and Firefox, adding this:

```
<style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html, body, #root {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        @media print {
            body {
                width: 130vw;
            }
        }
</style>
```

This CSS shrinks the content on the print preview for Chrome and Firefox, which is the intended feature as by default the rendered HTML appears far too large (and consequently uses too much paper).

Safari, however, instead of shrinking body, extends it 130% beyond the actual page. This causes parts of the HTML to not at all appear in the print.

How do I resolve this issue such that Safari's behavior remain consistent with the rest of the other browsers?

Comment: how about creating a separate class for safari and use pixels instead of vm

Comment: I have to use vw because I have no idea what the width is, all I know is I want the HTML to scale smaller on the print preview

Answer (score 0):

Please, use px

```
   <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            html, body, #root {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            @media print {
                body {
                    **width: 1024px;**
                }
            }
    </style>
```

You can also add a command, `@page` where it is used in safari

```
@page {
margin: 0cm !important;
}
```

Has no effect on Safari 6, where it does in Chrome 23. As I know, as long as Safari is not supporting this, there is no solution (it seems to be fixed to around 10mm).

The page setting as seen here you might have to define a custom "Paper Size" in the "Print…" menu panel without any margin (you did it already btw).

Obviously to take care of the other inner content html, body… not to have any margin.

Answer (score 0):

Using @JMF's solution alone did not work for me. However, this solution fixed the problem:

```
<style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            html, body, #root {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            @media print {
                body {
                    width: 1024px; /* Using px here */
                }

                body > div {
                    max-width: 1024px; /* Set container max-width to same width as body to avoid overflow */
                }
            }
    </style>
```